# How to edit exif gps information using javascript in html5 mobile web app

Tags: javascript, gps, exif

I am working on a html5 mobile web app and in that i am using getusermedia and video element to capture a picture. I am using only javascript, jquery and html5. And also i am using geolocation api for gps. How I can edit the exif data or gps information in the exif data using javascript ?

Please anyone help me in this..

Answer (score 1):

It seems this library can do this :

https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

 I tried with this but it is not working for me. If you got answer with this library then please help me, how i can apply this?

Comment: can you paste your code into codepen.io and give the url to see where the problem is ?